# Cumulative sum of matrix elements

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have a matrix defined as the pair-wise differences between the elements of an array:

```
a <- as.matrix(dist(c(1,2,3,4,5)))
```

I need to compute without looping the sum of the pair-wise differences between the first two elements, the first three elements, etc. i.e., I need to arrive to the array:

```
v <- c(1,4,10,20)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 head(cumsum(cumsum(1:5)),-1)
 #[1]  1  4 10 20
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you indeed want the to call the cumulative sum function twice, as I think "*the sum of the pair-wise differences between the first two elements, the first three elements, etc.*" should result in:

```
c(1, 3, 6, 10)
```

Anyway, this should work with non-sequential `x` as well for your required output:

```
> cumsumdiff <- function (x) cumsum(cumsum(sapply(x[-1], `-`, x[1])))
> cumsumdiff(1:5)
[1]  1  4 10 20
```

Or based on @Jota's suggestion using the distance matrix:

```
> cumsumdiff <- function(x) cumsum(cumsum(unname(as.matrix(dist(x))[1, -1])))
> cumsumdiff(1:5)
[1]  1  4 10 20
```